# how to create a .mat file with current time stamp in matlab?

Tags: matlab, time

I want to create a .mat file with current time stamp in matlab ? I want the name of the .mat file to be the current time.

Comment: Try the built-in now function...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `datestr` to format the time and use `now`to get the current time:

```
save(datestr(now,30))
```